# How to copy a file from one drive to another drive using a robocopy command in a batch file script

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, robocopy

How to copy a file from one drive to another drive using a robocopy in a batch file script.
The source path and destination path should be given as input by the user including the file name. Thanks in advance.

This is the code that i have tried.

```
      @REM Sample batch file

      Set /p filename1=Enter the source path:%=%
      Set /p fileparam=Enter the file name:%=%

      Set /p filename4=Enter destination path:%=%

      echo
      pause

      robocopy %filename1% %filename4% %fileparam%.txt /E /MIR

      echo
      pause
```

Comment: please try to type `HELP ROBOCOPY` on a command prompt.

Comment: That i tried @PA. but i need to create a batch file which should the file name as input from the user then it should copy in destination path..

Comment: show us please what you have tried. The easiest way to pass some input from the user to a BAT file is to pass a parameter in the command line, or an implied parameter from the explorer; and receive it as `%1` in the BAT.

Comment: Check the code which i have uploaded @PA.

Comment: and, what is your problem? is it failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   set /p Source_Folder="%Old_Client_Folder%"
   set /p Destination_Folder="%New_Client_Folder%"
   robocopy "\\%Old_Client_Folder%\" "\\\%New_Client_Folder%\" /MOVE /E
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation?

Comment: set /p will ask the user to enter the folder name they want to move, and ask what the destination folder will be called. Then robocopy will move the folders/files etc